# Examining Q-V characteristics of a Capacitor using LTSpice

Tags: capacitor, simulation, ltspice

Consider the following circuit:

[image]

I want to acquire Q-V characteristics of the *capacitor C* using that circuit, with LTSpice. How can I do this? Does LTSpice provide a straightforward method for measuring Q, or should I find an expression involving electrical laws and that can be evaluated using LTSpice?

(I am using LTSpice v4.23)

Comment: What "Q-V" characteristics? What is it you want to measure in electrical terms? The capacitor in LTSpice is ideal as long as you don't supply parameters.

Comment: You can measure dQ/dt in Spice.

Comment: Q=CV initial would apply for a step charge with DC input = CV output on big Cap except conservation of energy factors loss of I^2R*t in Ri or as Bri says for I=dQ/dt, in the end you have a partial Capacitive voltage divider like a resistive divider if Ri is low Cs/(Ci+Cs)*Vin=Vout

Comment: Of course the capacitor being used in LTSpice is ideal, but I want to see the expected characteristics using the other measurable quantities of the simulation, as one may use the methodology used in LTSpice in real oscilloscopes.

Comment: The integrator is useful in DSO measurements where fo<< ripple frequency then AC ripple is across R and pure DC is across integrator cap, which is why example shows 100Hz the frequency of a rectified 50Hz, then the integrator needs to be 8T or 80ms for 10% ripple or 50T for <<1% ripple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$ Q_C = \int i_C dt = \int \frac{v_1}{R_{100}} dt $$
So if you put a perfect integrator on \$R_{100}\$ then you are measuring \$Q_C\$ (times a constant).

Now for example, if you have Spice tabulate \$v_C\$ and \$Q_c\$ at various time and scatter-plot them on a graph, you should see them all fall on a straight line for an ideal C. The slope of the line would be:
$$ \frac{Q_c}{v_c} = C $$